# Do I need to add "da" before "to iimashita"?

Tags: grammar, translation, adjectives, copula

Not sure how to say "my mum said it was fun." Is this correct:

> watashi no okaasan wa, sore ga tanoshi to iimashita

Or do I need to add "da"? As this is for speaking.

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add a clarification to user4092's answer:

In English, *present tense verbs are changed to past tense in reported speech*.

"My mum said it **was** fun" would mean that she said she had fun **as the activity was going on**. If this is what you meant, then the Japanese sentence below is the answer:

> English direct speech: *My mum said, "This is fun!"*
>
> English reported speech: *My mum said it was fun.*
>
> Japanese reported speech: *watashi no haha wa **tanoshii** to iimashita*

"My mum said it **had been** fun" would mean the mother said she had fun **after the activity was over**. If this is what you meant, then the Japanese sentence below is the answer:

> English direct speech: *My mum said, "That was fun!"*
>
> English reported speech: *My mum said it had been fun.*
>
> Japanese reported speech: *watashi no haha wa **tanoshikatta** to iimashita*

Please note:

1. *tanoshii* conjugates to *tanoshikatta* (for *i*-adjectives, drop the last *i* and add *katta*)
2. Change *iimashita* to *itta* for plain form. (As in user4092's answer.)
3. I would also like to point out that *tanoshii* in your original sentence is missing an *i*.
4. Add *da* when an indirect quote ends with a *na*-adjective or noun...

> *watashi no haha wa **kirei da** to iimashita* (My mum said it was beautiful.)
>
> *watashi no haha wa **hana da** to iimashita* (My mum said it was a flower / they were flowers.)

...but not when an indirect quote ends with an *i*-adjective or verb:

> *watashi no haha wa **tanoshii** to iimashita* (My mum said it was fun.)
>
> *watashi no haha wa **ashita iku** to iimashita* (My mum said she would go the next day.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need it. But you should translate "my mom" to "(watashi-no) haha" and "it was fun" to "tanoshikatta", as a whole "(watashi-no) haha-wa tanoshikatta-to itta".

Comment: Colloquially, you could call your own mother お母さん, and considering the poster says 'my mum' rather than 'my mother' I think it fits. It does sound a little childish, though.

Comment: I might have dragged with "watashi-no".

Comment: @user4092 I guess the "watashi-no" provides some context. In any case, I did start out with longer (and thus less confusing) sentences when beginning with romaji, though.